# Is there any case in which the `cd .` (single dot) command could be useful?

Tags: filesystems, cd-command

This should theoretically just be redundant since it changes into the current working directory. Anyway, is there any scenario in practice, where this command could be useful?

Answer (score 5):

At least two cases comes immediately to my mind where `cd .` can be useful:

- Update the inode number of the current directory

  Let's say in *terminal1* you are inside some directory and in another *terminal2* you delete this directory and create new directory with the same name as deleted one. Then to be able to do whatever useful inside this directory (e.g. create a file) in *termminal1* you can do `cd .` what will update the inode number of this directory.
- Resolve directories physically

  If directory name is a symbolic link, you can `cd -P .` to resolve link components physically. This feature comes directly from POSIX. Yes, this requires `-P` option, so its not bare `cd .`, but still...

Comment: The first point only works in some shells because when you do `cd .` there, they blindly do the equivalent of `cd -P -- "$PWD"` even if $PWD doesn't correspond to the current working directory anymore. ksh93 here would still do a `chdir(".")` upon `cd .` which would leave you in your deleted directory like `cd -P .` would. Same for shells that don't implement that logical directory traversal upon `cd`.

Answer (score 4):

There's another minor effect, it sets `$OLDPWD`.

That variable should be empty when you start a new terminal until you `cd` to somewhere.

And there's one possible usage that I can think of, which might not be very useful (and a bit naive) but here it is:

`cd -` navigates to `$OLDPWD`, so you can use in combination with `cd .` to navigate forth and back to the same directory after some operation:

```
cd .; for i in {1..100}; do cd -;mkdir "d$i"; cd "d$i"; touch a; done
```

Not something I'd do in a script, but maybe directly in the command line or some code golfing...

Comment: Even for golfing, it'd be better to use a subshell if you want the effects of  a `cd` to be lost: `for i in {1..100}; do (mkdir "d$i"; cd "d$i"; touch a); done`

Comment: `mkdir "d$i" && touch "d$i"/a` :-)

Comment: @muru Well, if you have to set some variable, then you'll lose that if in a subshell... but you know, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

While `cd .` is essentially a null operation, I can see a case where `pushd .` might presumably be relevant.

Also, in a script where a target directory is specified interactively, procedurally, or from an argument, a command such as:

```
cd $destinationpath
```

may evaluate to

```
cd .
```

should the variable be so assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's also very useful if you want to create empty file with CMD. Just use this trick:

`cd . > filename.ext`

Comment: `true` and `:` are more canonical for that. In several shells including Bourne-like ones other than zsh, you can even just do `> filename.ext`.

Comment: Note that this also has the side effect of resetting the OLDPWD shell variable to the pathname of the current directory. If you rely on "cd -" to take you to the most recent work directory, this would affect the behaviour of that command.